# How Check current PHP session set or unset

Tags: php, session, authentication

Guys in my php project i want to check on Login page session's status..if its unset i want user to login.
ihave added this code to login page but it doesn't help as it loops.

```
if (strlen(session_id()) < 1) {
    ?>
    <script>window.location.href="login.php";</script>  
    <?php     
}
elseif(strlen(session_id()) > 1){ 
    ?>   
    <script>window.location.href="index.php";</script>   
    <?php 
}
```

Now other thing I want is if session is already started and if user manually tries to go on login page from address bar he should be redirected back to that current page.

If he is not logged in he should be redirected back to login page if he tries to open directly any page.

Also a new doubt with this is
Guys i m using wamp server to run my PHP projects.I have used PHP sessions in my projects,Now when a user logins from one project the sessions get set and if on same pc if user open some other project which are not linked to each other he gets directly logged in without even doing it, if he logouts from one project he gets logout from all other project running on that pc.

Comment: you want to be checking for a particular session value, not the existence of a session .. if $_SESSION['logged_in']==1 ....

Comment: k.so during initial login i should set logged_in =1 and than compare it on login page and empty it during logout.??

Comment: that's how its mostly done - posted as answer below so you can accept it (or not)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == 1) {
        //session is set
        header('Location: /index.php');
    } else if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || (isset($_SESION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == 0)){
        //session is not set
        header('Location: /login.php');
    }
?>
```

In reply to above comments, yes you should create a session variable when the user is logged in. Edited code to reflect it.

Comment: guys if i use php's `header('Location: /login.php');` its nt redirecting properly and if i use JavaScript window.location its looping again.

Comment: Do you get an error when using the header? Can you post your full code?

Comment: firefox shows me this The page isn't redirecting properly..but header thing works properly for my other projects.

Comment: `<?php

    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['logged_in']==1) {
        //session is set
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else{
        //session is not set
        header("Location: login.php");
    }


?>`    below this is my html login page.

Comment: dude its working fine if logged_in = 1 but its not redirecting for else loop.also my logout page as this `<?php session_start();
session_destroy();
?>

<script>
 window.location.href="login.php";
</script>` does this cause any problem

Comment: Change your logout page to this:<?

 session_start();
 session_unset();
 session_destroy();
 
 header('Location: /');
?>

Comment: no success dude..if comment header line of else than it works properly or else it doesn't load login page,also initially it doesn't loads login page on project start.

Comment: if i change it to any other page it loads it properly...bt doean't load login page.

Comment: Do some debugging. Add the line "echo $_SESSION['logged_in'];" before the if statement and change your code based on the output.

Comment: dude it doesn't show anything during initial login or after logout in echo.

Comment: That's probably because the headers are redirecting you. Comment them out and see if that helps.

Comment: dude its showing nothing as we destroy session..and if i remove header of else loop it everythng wrks properly..even if i replace login page with some othr page it redirects properly....

Comment: problem is it doesn't redirect on login page if session variable is = 0;

Comment: Updated answer. It will redirect to /login if the $_SESSION['logged_in'] is not set or if it is equal to 0.

Answer (score 2):

you want to be checking for a particular session value, not the existence of a session ..

```
if ($_SESSION['logged_in']==1){

//
}else{

//
}
```

set $_SESSION['logged_in'] to 1  on log in and unset it (or set it to 0) on logout

Answer (score 0):

1. Remember to include session_start(); on the top of every page to get the values of variable SET in the SESSION through $_SESSION['example'], otherwise You will not be able to the session Variable values ,
   OR

---

1. A different Approach is to use session_start(); inside config.php file and include that file on the top of the code of every page where sessions are required otherwise U will not be able to get the value of SESSION variable..!!